# "Napoleon complex" or "Napoleonic complex"?

Tags: proper-nouns, morphology, modifiers

Which is correct: "he has a Napoleon complex" or "he has a Napoleonic complex"?

Comment: why off topic??

Comment: Please never just ask “Which is correct?”  It shows no effort on your part, and gives us nothing to go on.  As [the Help Center says in its “How to ask a good question” section](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask):  **“Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!”** Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right term is *Napoleon complex*.

Answer (score 0):

[Napoleon complex](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon_complex), or *"short man syndrome"*,

> is a pejorative slang term describing a type of *psychological phenomenon which is said to exist in people, usually men, of short stature.* It is characterized by overly-aggressive or domineering social behaviour, and carries the implication that such behaviour is compensatory for the subjects' stature. The term is also used more generally to describe people who are driven by a perceived handicap to overcompensate in other aspects of their lives. Other names for the term include Napoleon syndrome and Short Man syndrome.

[Napoleonic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Napoleonic)
adj

> (Historical Terms) relating to or characteristic of Napoleon I or his era,  like " The Napoleonic wars".